# How to monitor perm gen space remotely?

Tags: remote, permgen

I need some help on how to monitor perm gen space remotely. We have Tomcat installed on Windows 2008 R2. From time to time perm gen space is full. I want to monitor the perm gen space before it becomes full so that certain actions can be done to prevent service disruptions. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [JMX remoting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) - it provides a way to get a look at the permgen size as well as a lot of other information about the running Java instance.

You'll probably want to use authentication and encryption, but adding just this to your Java options should get you started:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

How you monitor this will depend on your monitoring software, but to monitor manually, use [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) from the JDK and configure a remote instance.

Comment: Thanks, uhm how to set that? Sorry for asking noob questions cause I really am a noob.

Comment: @GejutelK.Landegre See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/79641/how-can-i-configure-tomcat-java-options-in-a-config-file) - probably the easiest method is to use the tomcat config management app (`tomcat6w.exe` or 5 or 7 depending on which version you're on) - the Java tab, Java Options box.